# How can I solve following pattern equations in SymPy, like (x-1)**2+y**2=0?

Tags: python, math, sympy

I want to solve the following equations: `(x-1)**2+y**2=0`, I want to get the result like: x = 1, y = 0, but the below code doesn't work.

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols("x")
y = symbols("y")

expression = [(x-1)**2+y**2]

solve(expression,[x,y])
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? Please be more specific.

Comment: I only get the Imaginary number solution [(-I*(x - 1),), (I*(x - 1),)]

Comment: Works for me; `[(-I*y + 1, y), (I*y + 1, y)]`. It's a quadratic; two solutions. Note that it gives `x = f(y)` and just `y=y` as there is obviously a family of solutions parameterized by `y`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for integer solutions then `diophantine` might be what you want:

```
>>> diophantine((x-1)**2+y**2, (x,y))
{(1, 0)}
```